# "Expression result unused" error in for loop

Tags: c

I'm trying to separate integers stored in array into their separate digits and then add all the separated digits up. The following code is throwing back an `expression result unused` for the `j / 10` portion of my for loop and I'm not sure why. `j` should be set to the ith variable in the array and as long as `j` is still above `1`, should divide by `10` and execute the following code. Can anyone explain what's wrong here.

```
int sum = 0;
int digit;
int number;
for (int i = 0; i < cclen / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = cc2nd[i]; j > 1; j / 10) {
        number = cc2nd[i];
        digit = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        sum = sum + digit;
    }
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually assigning anything in that statement, just performing an operation and discarding the result. You probably want `j /= 10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
j / 10
```

doesn't change `j` at all, you keep testing the same expression all over again, and the compiler probably even optimizes out the test. Do you mean

```
j /= 10
```

instead?